# Migration issue: Drupal markup isn't rendered on CiviCRM pages

Tags: civicrm

I've moved a Drupal 6 / CiviCRM 4.3 site to a development server, and I'm getting really strange behavior. When I visit a Drupal page on the copied site, everything renders as expected. However, when I visit a CiviCRM page, the CMS part of the markup is missing from the source. It's almost like every CiviCRM page is being delivered as a snippet.

To be more specific, when I go to /civicrm and view source, I get markup beginning with:

```
<div id="crm-container" class="crm-container" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<div id="menu-container" style="display:none;">
  <ul id="civicrm-menu">
  ...
```

The opening and closing HTML tags, and all the HTML contained in the Drupal theme are entirely absent. The same appears to be true for every CiviCRM page.

I've tried the following:

- reviewing my CiviCRM settings file
- reviewing my directory and resource settings
- clearing Drupal caches
- emptying sites/default/civicrm/templates_c
- deleting sites/default/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/Config.IDS.ini
- running `drush civicrm-update-cfg`
- checking error logs for Apache, Drupal, and CiviCRM
- throwing salt over my left shoulder

Any ideas what might cause such strange behavior? Suggestions for something I might have missed in my migration or a good place to put debugging code to get to the bottom of this?

Comment: So what's in your logs? Server's error.log, Drupal's watchdog, and whatever it is CiviCRM is using? And have you made sure CiviCRM is actually called at all? If Drupal does not call it, it's Drupal's fault. If it does, but CiviCRM returns nothing, it's not.

Comment: Did you have CiviCRM Theme module on at your old location?

Comment: I wonder if you are seeing what's left of an open output buffer after things die in Smarty space?

You will have already taken a close look at logs, but look again and make absolutely sure you're seeing all the output you could be. If it's exiting early there should be some notice.

Your dev environment might not suit drupal6.

Not really an answer sorry :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ah, I think I've seen this before, did you by chance mess with your CiviCRM settings file?

Double-check your `CIVICRM_UF` setting, Civi might be tripping up if it thinks the CMS is something other than what it actually is.

For Drupal 6 you want `CIVICRM_UF = 'Drupal6'`

Comment: The lesson is to minimize the amount of programming you do after midnight. I had indeed somehow managed to set the UF to Drupal instead of Drupal6. Imagine that: CiviCRM needs to know what the CMS is in order to render the CMS chrome.

Comment: Heh ginkgoMZD, if you ask and answer enough questions to get 200 reputation that will help CiviCRM launch its own StackExchange site (http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77367/civicrm). Cheers, Joe

Comment: I've had this happen to me before too. It's confusing when everything stops working for no apparent reason, and you're thinking "I must have done something really dumb, but which really dumb thing did I do?"